# Is this a switch loop?

Tags: networking, switch

I have a quesion regarding creating switch loops.
I have 1 server with 2 network cards (nic1 and nic2) and 2 switches (sw1 and sw2)

Question:
Am I creating a switch loop if I connect nic1 to sw1 and nic2 to sw2 and I cascade sw1 and sw2?

NOTE: no spanning tree in place

Comment: It would only be a switch loop if the server were acting as a bridge/switch.

Answer (score 5):

Not unless you install some kind of bridge on the PC with the two NIC's, no.
This is a pretty standard setup for a redundant network.

Your situation mirrors an example in the [ciscopress switch redundancy article.](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=102268&seqNum=3)

Comment: sorry but as you realized already I am quite noob on this, would you be able to tell me how do you setup a bridge on the PC?

Comment: @masuberu: This would be a separate question, but you should read [this](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) to check if your question is appropriate here or if it isn't better suited at [SU] ([Help Center](http://superuser.com/help), [topic-list](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)).